# How to use nested IF-THEN constraints in DOCPLEX (Python)?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, docplex

I am modeling the situation I want using python cplex.
While using it, a few questions arose, and these are:

1. Can I use nested IF-THEN constraints in CPLEX?

First, I could find below how to use the basic IF-THEN constraint.

[How to use Continuous Variables for IF-THEN constraints on DOCPLEX (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58853258/how-to-use-continuous-variables-for-if-then-constraints-on-docplex-python)

However, I couldn't find a way to use nested IF-THEN constraints even there, so I did some thinking.

To explain by citing the answer above, I want the following situation:

```
mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')  
**mdl.add(mdl.if_then(((nbbus40>=3) and (nbbus40<=7)),(nbbus30>=7)))**
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)
```

If I try something like line 5 of the code above, can't I use nested IF-THEN constraints?

If this is wrong, how should I use nested IF-THEN constraints?

2. In general, I understand that inequality can be used as a constraint in CPLEX.
   For example, if I want to give the condition of A=1, I can satisfy it by giving both the condition A>=1 and the condition A<=1.
   My question is, is there a way to specify (constrain) a value using only the equal sign (I think 2 conditions in 1 constraint is wasteful)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Making optimization simple with python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/) you relied on [if then](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooifthen.py) but you should try [if then (v2)](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooifthen2.py)

With your model I would write

```
mdl.add((mdl.logical_and((nbbus40>=3),(nbbus40<=7)))<=(nbbus30>=7))
```

instead of

```
mdl.add(mdl.if_then(((nbbus40>=3) and (nbbus40<=7)),(nbbus30>=7)))
```

Full example:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3  and less than 7 then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint

mdl.add((mdl.logical_and((nbbus40>=3),(nbbus40<=7)))<=(nbbus30>=7))

mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

 

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value) 

'''

which gives

nbBus40  =  6.0
nbBus30  =  2.0

with if nb buses 40 more than 3  and less than 7 then nbBuses30 more than 7
nbBus40  =  8.0
nbBus30  =  0.0

'''
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
By the way, in the case of IF_THEN(A and B, C), this example seems to work well, but how should I write the code in case IF_THEN(A and (B or C), D)? Should I write logical_or nested?

Comment: mdl.add((mdl.logical_and((nbbus40>=3),mdl.logical_or(nbbus40<=7,nbbus30>=2)))<=(nbbus30>=7)) works fine

Comment: Thank you. I've tested your answers and confirmed that they all work.