# Creating and/or logic between constraints DOcplex python

Tags: python-3.x, cplex, docplex

I'm trying to transfer my constraints from Cplex OPT studio to the DOcplex Python.

The logic between the constraints is - if 1 of them does not met all the decision variables needs to be 0.

In Cplex Studio its look like that:

```
forall(r in risk_list) (0.2 * sum (i in funds) x[i][r]* risk[i] >=  r - 0.005) && (sum(i in funds)  x[i][r] == 5)|| sum (i in funds)x[i][r]==0;
```

How can I define "OR" "AND" logic between the constraints?

Answer (score 0):

It's [not always a good idea to move from OPL to python](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/optimization-aka-prescriptive-analytics-should-we-write-fleischer/). And [from python you can also call an OPL model](https://pypi.org/project/doopl/).

But in docplex you can use logical constraints.

See [How to Implement Logical OR constraint in CPLEX Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710025/how-to-implement-logical-or-constraint-in-cplex-python)

[zoological.py](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoological.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*460 + nbbus30*360)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with the logical constraint")

nbKindOfBuses = mdl.integer_var(name='nbKindOfBuses')
mdl.add(nbKindOfBuses==(nbbus40>=1)+(nbbus30>=1))

mdl.minimize(nbbus40*460 + nbbus30*360+(nbKindOfBuses-1)*(500))

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

[zooifthen.py](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooifthen.py)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)

print()
print("with if nb buses 40 more than 3  then nbBuses30 more than 7")

#if then constraint
mdl.add(mdl.if_then(nbbus40>=3,nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

 

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your comment. I tried to use the first example and i go an error. the logical constraints is:Mymodel.add((sum(0.2 * x [i,r] * risk_dict[i] for i in id) <= r + 0.005) + (sum(0.2 * x [i,r] * risk_dict[i] for i in id) >= r - 0.005) >=1 for r in risk_list)
and i get the error:"    raise DOcplexException(resolved_message)
docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexException: Conversion from constraint to expression is available only for discrete constraints,"

Comment: One more question - Do you know how to call the Cplex OPL model from python?

Comment: i tried to install doopl and the error is : Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement doopl (from versions: none)

Comment: With float constraints you could use indicators , see https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooifthencontinuous.py. Many ways to call OPL from python : doopl, ticdat https://pypi.org/project/ticdat/ or call OPL with oplrun https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/dietpythoncallOPL.py

Comment: Do you know if its possible also for "Logical_and" with constraints variables? and do you have an example of how to change the variables format result for the ModelReader?

Comment: And https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooand.py Or https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zooor.py